# Visual Studio 2010 - Datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to bind a particular column in datagridview to another datasource, while all other columns are bound to same datasource as the gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not directly. You could load an array or XML from two sources then bind that, but you can't bind it directly.